# How can I open a port on open shift?

Tags: openshift-client-tools, openshift-origin

I'm trying to open a port on open shift for a java application. But when I run the app I get this error

```
  There was an error binding to port 1701.  Port already in use.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to your app externally using HTTP, you can only bind your app to 8080. [Here's](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html) a summary.
(Ports 15000 - 35530 are available for binding internal IP, but these ports are not externally addressable.)

Comment: There was an error binding to port 8080.  Port already in use.

Comment: You can ssh into your app `rhc ssh <yourApp>` and run `lsof` to see what is bound to the port, but I would expect a web server or the main application that comes with the cartridge you have deployed would be there. I recommend editing your question and elaborating on what is your environment, what cartridge have you used and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I already have something using port 8080, How can I kill the process?